# How to trigger pipeline in Jenkins with Github Webhook

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

I would like to triggered one pipeline with Github webhook. This pipeline is connected with my Github Repository and a Github webhook.

I want to trigger this pipeline with informations in the webhook as the ID_commit, Github branch, or other things.

For example : `if BRANCH == master : Build Pipeline`

I try to use 2 plugins but it doesn't works :

- [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin)
- [Jenkins github webhook build trigger plugin](https://github.com/codeclou/jenkins-github-webhook-build-trigger-plugin)

Comment: Maybe Should I create a Bash script ? Or maybe I have missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

The webhook being sent from GitHub on push looks like this:
https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent

```
...
{
  "ref": "refs/heads/changes",
  "before": "9049f1265b7d61be4a8904a9a27120d2064dab3b",
  "after": "0d1a26e67d8f5eaf1f6ba5c57fc3c7d91ac0fd1c",
  "created": false,
...
```

To get the branch (ref) into a variable you need to configure a JSONPath parameter. Like maby variable `ref` and expression `$.ref`

To trigger only if branch is `master` you need to configure a filter. In Optional filter, specify *regexp* as `master` and *text* as `$ref`

Also, as the wiki suggests, troubleshooting this with `curl` is probably easiest.